# Add more than 14 parameters to OracleParameterCollection

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a problem with inserting data into a table.
The table is actually very large; it has more than 100 fields, 
and I tried to set parameters using C# and OracleParameterCollection (System.Data.OracleClient) like this:

```
var param = new OracleParameter(":pEmpNo1", OracleType.Number);
param.Value = 1;
command.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new OracleParameter(":pEmpNo2", OracleType.Number);
param.Value = 2;
command.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new OracleParameter(":pEmpNo3", OracleType.Number);
param.Value = 3;
command.Parameters.Add(param);
    :
    :
param = new OracleParameter(":pEmpNo14", OracleType.Number);
param.Value = 14;
command.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new OracleParameter(":pEmpNo15", OracleType.Number);
param.Value = 15;
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

And my SQL looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (
    pEmpNo1,
    pEmpNo2,
    pEmpNo3,
    pEmpNo4,
    pEmpNo5,
    pEmpNo6,
    pEmpNo7,
    pEmpNo8,
    pEmpNo9,
    pEmpNo10,
    pEmpNo11,
    pEmpNo12,
    pEmpNo13,
    pEmpNo14,
    pEmpNo15
) VALUES (
    :pEmpNo1,
    :pEmpNo2,
    :pEmpNo3,
    :pEmpNo4,
    :pEmpNo5,
    :pEmpNo6,
    :pEmpNo7,
    :pEmpNo8,
    :pEmpNo9,
    :pEmpNo10,
    :pEmpNo11,
    :pEmpNo12,
    :pEmpNo13,
    :pEmpNo14,
    :pEmpNo15
);
```

When I execute the program, an error "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" occurred. However, when I reduce adding parameter less than 15 (for example, delete "pEmpNo15" from both my SQL and oracleParameterCollection), it work just fine. I don't know why, and somehow I want to add more than 14 parameters to the OracleParameterCollection. Please let me know if you have any information, thank you in advance!

**Update：**
I corrected the SQL sample code (I removed last comma wrongly inserted in front of ") VALUES ("). Still I have the same issue...

Comment: Not answering the question, but `System.Data.OracleClient` is deprecated (check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7(v=vs.110).aspx), and may have bugs and arbitrary limits. I'd try and find a third party provider

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the last column "pEmpNo15," (note the comma) it should be change to "pEmpNo15" (no comma)

Your query should looks like :

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (
    pEmpNo1,
    pEmpNo2,
    pEmpNo3,
    pEmpNo4,
    pEmpNo5,
    pEmpNo6,
    pEmpNo7,
    pEmpNo8,
    pEmpNo9,
    pEmpNo10,
    pEmpNo11,
    pEmpNo12,
    pEmpNo13,
    pEmpNo14,
    pEmpNo15
) VALUES (
    :pEmpNo1,
    :pEmpNo2,
    :pEmpNo3,
    :pEmpNo4,
    :pEmpNo5,
    :pEmpNo6,
    :pEmpNo7,
    :pEmpNo8,
    :pEmpNo9,
    :pEmpNo10,
    :pEmpNo11,
    :pEmpNo12,
    :pEmpNo13,
    :pEmpNo14,
    :pEmpNo15
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
I corrected my sample sql. Actually, this issue is not coming from the comma wrongly replaced after "pEmpNo15." I don't know why but the error "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" occurred if I tried to add more than 14 parameters to OracleParameterCollection. It works just fine if I cut any of the parameters (let's say "pEmpNo7" for example). If you know something, please let me know. I really appreciate your help!